# JavaFX retrieving an object

Tags: java, javafx-2, scenebuilder

just wondering is there anyway I can retrieve and modify an object in a JavaFX scene given its x and y coordinates? I have looked through the documentation but cannot see anything that will do the trick.
Thank you

edit: Just to add I've developed the scene with scene builder and their are multiple objects.